# Double differentiation of inverse function

Tags: functions

Let f(x) = $x^3 +3x +1$ and g(x)  is the inverse of f(x) then what is the value of g''(5).

In this I know f(1) =5 and g(5)=1

now how to proceed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$g(f(x))=x$$
$$g^{'}(f(x)).f^{'}(x)=1$$
$$g^{"}(f(x)).f^{'}(x)+g^{'}(f(x)).f^{"}(x)=0$$

Rest you have every thing to get your answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Starting  from $y=f(x)$ we have $$1)  \qquad x=f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(f(x))$$ and differentiating :

$$
\frac{d}{dx} x= \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))$$ that is
$$ 2) \qquad
 1=\left[f^{-1}(f(x))\right]' f'(x)
$$
from wich we find the first derivative of the inverse function:

$$
\left[f^{-1}(f(x))\right]'=\frac{1}{f'(x)} \iff \left[f^{-1}(y)\right]'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}
$$

differentiating $2)$( with the product and chain rules) we find:
$$
0= \left[f^{-1}(f(x))\right]''\left( f'(x)\right)^2 +f''(x)\left[f^{-1}(f(x)) \right]'
$$

that gives:

$$
\left[f^{-1}(f(x))\right]''=-f''(x)\frac{1}{\left(f'(x)\right)^3}
$$

or:
$$
\left[f^{-1}(y)\right]''=-f''(f^{-1}(y))\frac{1}{\left(f'(f^{-1}(y))\right)^3}
$$

so you can find $f'$ and $f''$ and you know that $f^{-1}(5)=1$.